# element of each array divide by 2

Tags: java

In this array, I am trying to output half of each element after each loop until all element of array becomes zero like [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. Let's say my array is [3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1] but my program does this after each element is zero then go to the next one.
Day 1 [1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]
Day 2 [0, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]
Day 3 [0, 3, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]
Day 4 [0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]
Day 5 [0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]
...
 How do I half each element after each loop like this;

Day 0 [3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 0]
Day 1 [3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0]
Day 2 [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Day 3 [3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0]
Day 4 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Day 5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zombi2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean cond = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] inhabitants = new int[8];
        for(int i=0; i<inhabitants.length; i++) {
          inhabitants[i] = input.nextInt();
        }


        for(int x : inhabitants) {
            if(x != 0) cond =  true;
        }

        int t = 1;
        while(cond) {
            cond = false;
            for(int x=0; x<inhabitants.length; x++) {
                while(inhabitants[x]>0) {
                    inhabitants[x] = inhabitants[x]/2;
                    if(inhabitants[x] != 0) cond = true;
                    System.out.println("Day " + t + " " + Arrays.toString(inhabitants));
                    t++;
                }
            }
        }


        do {
            for(int x : inhabitants) {
                if(x != 0) cond =  true;
            }
        }while(cond);
        System.out.println("---- EXTINCT ----");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do because your example conflicts with your explanation. If you are halving all elements each day, and day 0 is `[3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 0]`, then shouldn't day 1 be `[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0]` and not `[3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0]`?

Comment: Yes, so I guess that is one mistake, explanation is correct my code was wrong, so yes I should start from 0, my original array should be [3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1] and day 0 should be [3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 0] and so on,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must swap the loops. The `while` loop must be the outer and the `for` loop the inner:  
 I presume all integers are positive so by checking if their sum is 0 the loop stops.  
I think this will work:

```
    int sum = 1;
    int day = 1;
    while (sum > 0) {
        sum = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < inhabitants.length; x++) {
            if (inhabitants[x] > 0)
                inhabitants[x] = inhabitants[x] / 2;
            sum += inhabitants[x];
        }
        System.out.println("Day " + day + " " + Arrays.toString(inhabitants));
        day++;
    }
```

Comment: Why the test for `> 0`? --- Also, why not use `/=`?

Comment: @Andreas I kept OP's code for the `/=` issue as for the `>` it's just for clarity. The result is the same. Anyway I will edit because I left out code that OP needs.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but it doesn't output like this Day 0 [3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 0]
Day 1 [3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0]
Day 2 [3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
Day 3 [3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0]
Day 4 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Day 5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: @James you understand that this example you provided is wrong? Why the 1st element remains 3 in day 1? It should be 1 already.

Comment: @James Don't you want all elements to be half in day 1?

Comment: Sorry guys, yes the program is right, one more thing how do we make each item be divided by two if it is adjacent(left or right) to an element with zero, until all item equals zero? So instead of dividing each item by two after each loop, we check if item is equal to zero, and then we check left or right item and try to half these item, and continue this process until all items equal to zero.

Comment: @James First thing that comes in mind is that this would be impossible in case there is not a 0 in the initial array. So there is a case that there is no solution. Second you check something like `if ((a[i-1]==0) || (a[i+1]==0) {a[i]=a[i]/2}`